# Pandas DataFrame.loc returns Empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently trying to work through some tutorials. Right now I have a pandas Dataframe with stock data. The stock data was taken by reading a csv file, then using `df.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)` I set the index to use 'timestamp'. The head is seen here:

```
 timestamp   open   high    low   close  adjusted_close   volume  dividend_amount  split_coefficient
2018-09-11  74.95  75.69  74.76  75.64           75.64  2225700              0.0                1.0
2018-09-10  75.10  75.21  74.84  74.91           74.91  1774400              0.0                1.0
2018-09-07  75.20  75.20  74.72  75.01           75.01  1804800              0.0                1.0
2018-09-06  74.95  75.55  74.62  75.24           75.24  3058300              0.0                1.0
2018-09-05  75.03  75.42  74.80  74.95           74.95  2418400              0.0                1.0
```

When I try `df.loc['2018-09-05']`, it returns the correct row to me. However, when I try to select a range, such as `df.loc['2018-09-05':'2018-09-11']`, I get an Empty DataFrame returned as so:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [open, high, low, close, adjusted_close, volume, dividend_amount, 
split_coefficient]
Index: []
```

Was wondering if anyone could provide any insight as to why this is happening? I would have expected a return of the information between the two dates instead of the empty dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort_index()` before slicing would work:

```
df = df.sort_index()
df['2018-09-05':'2018-09-11']
```

or

```
df = df.sort_index()
df.loc['2018-09-05':'2018-09-11']
```

---

FYI: If you want to make sure that index is `DatetimeIndex` before making `'timestamp'` as index:

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
```

or after the fact:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: And one idea - Maybe `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` if not `DatetimeIndex` ;)

Comment: @ jezrael - Thanks. That may be true even if `df.loc['2018-09-05']` worked and `df.loc['2018-09-05':'2018-09-11']` does not if it is not converted to DatetimeIndex. I'll try to test here and if that's the case I'll edit it.

Comment: exactly same idea - another possible problem if not matched ;)

Comment: @ jezrael it turns out that `df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)` and then `df = df.set_index('timestamp')` is the way the above solution to be working. If `df = df.set_index('timestamp')` and then `df = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` then above code does not work since `DatetimeIndex` does not accept `loc` or `sort_index`. I did not know that.

Comment: There is typo, need `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`  not `df = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: Phew....My bad...Now all the mystery is solved. I'll update my answer. Thanks again @jezrael.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to insert your index correctly from up to bottom. 
Try this for specific indexing:

```
df.loc['2018-09-11':'2018-09-05']
```

But you can use `sort()` to sort your index.
You can also use the ID for this.

Answer (score 0):

If the `timestamp` column is Pandas Timestamp, You can do something like this.

```
mask = (df['timestamp'] >= pd.Timestamp('2018-09-05')) & (df['timestamp'] <= pd.Timestamp('2018-09-11'))

df.loc[mask, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to reverse dates from newer to older and it will work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('some.csv', delimiter=";", index_col='timestamp')
range = df.loc['2018-09-11':'2018-09-05']
print(range)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change the date format

```
df.loc['05/09/2018': '11/09/2018']
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.